# Keytool error java.io.FileNotFoundException(the system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keytool

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: api.sepa.express.crt (The system cannot find the file specified)

I tried various examples which I found in stackoverflow.

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

and

```
    keytool -import -alias susan
   -file Example.cer -keystore exampleraystore
```

Tried using cmd as admin. I have placed my certificate file in Desktop. When I'm trying to copy in:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security

It's not accepting the certificate file.

What would be the preferred way to complete this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the ssl file using command promt. It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Firstly download the certificate into any of your directory, for me I choose (D:\My) where I kept my certificate with the name `xyz.cert`.

Second, you should be the admin of CMD/Command and write the word "keytool", it should give you the output as :

> Key and Certificate Management Tool

Commands:

```
 -certreq            Generates a certificate request
 -changealias        Changes an entry's alias
 -delete             Deletes an entry
...something like this should be the output
```

Third, As all the certificate are kept "cacerts" which is in the directory -
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\security`

Use the below command from the directory -
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\security`

> keytool -import -alias clojars.org -keystore  /cacerts -file
> D:/My/xyz.cer

Where to find what :

1. When you double click on the certificate (xyz.cert in my case) it
   will open a pop up, where you will find in General Tab, Issued to
   : `clojars.org` ( this name you need to give in front of -alias)
2. In front of -keystore should be the path of cacerts but as we are
   already in the directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\lib\security`, so we can just give
   /cacerts
3. file --> location of the certificate

If it asks for password, default is changeit, so keep the same everytime

Hope this solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

just create file in any other directory than c: Drive
for eg: create in d: Drive

Comment: Please provide more information than just "create a file in another directory". Why would this fix the problem the user is currently fixing?

Answer (score 0):

1.Advice:  run Comand Prompt as administrator ( If you are using windows 7, you can go to run, type cmd and hit Ctrl+Shift+enter. This will open the command prompt in administrator mode.)

2.C:......  >  keytool -importcert -file "C:part/to/file.crt" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias 1Alias
(Do not forget that file with .crt )

3.password - changeit

4. y  - yes.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the similar error when I was trying to run the BAT file:

> D:\Accela\av.biz\conf\certs>D:\Accela\bin\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\keytool.exe
> -import - noprompt -alias stgdiitehsccatsii.health.dohmh.nycnet -keystore D:\Accela\av.biz \conf\certs\trusted_cacerts -file D:\Accela\av.biz\conf\certs\stgdiitehsccatsii. health.dohmh.nycnet.cer
> -storepass changeit **keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:** D:\Accela\av.biz\conf\certs\stgdii tehsccatsii.health.dohmh.nycnet.cer
> (The system cannot find the file specified)
>
> D:\Accela\av.biz\conf\certs>pause Press any key to continue . . .

I was able to fix it just changing the extension from **.cer** to **.crt** on the BAT file code:

> D:\Accela\av.biz\conf\certs\stgdiitehsccatsii.health.dohmh.nycnet.**cer**

to

> D:\Accela\av.biz\conf\certs\stgdiitehsccatsii.health.dohmh.nycnet.**crt**

Since that was the right extension for the certificate file.